# Windows: Remotely add OU Domain and assign the access rights

Tags: windows, active-directory

The background:

1. Multiple OU Domains have been created.
2. I want to add these domains with specific/different access rights to hundreds of machines.
3. I have a script that is able to add the OU in the machine provided I have RDP to it.

Question:

How do I effectively do this without going to rdp to each machine?

Comment: Weird, simul-edit, with nearly the same result.

Comment: -1... closing: The question is simply one thing: not making sense. There is no such thing as a OU Domain.

Comment: Noted, maye the psexec is the answer after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your terminology - Are we talking about OUs, Groups or Domains here? They're all very different things. Could you clarify this?

Regarding your question about executing a script across many workstations without remoting onto them: You should be able to achieve this with [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).

Comment: My script has multiple lines of:
# net Localgroup "Backup Operators" WINDOW_LEVEL1 /add

Comment: Ok, and what os that was clarifying? Seriously - get your terminology right. I dont understand it wither.

Comment: I agree that my terminology is confusing.
Though in the end, I just want to execute commands on remote computer with I'm logging in to the server.
So using psexec should be do-able.